# How to draw a chord of ellipse with specific center point and the points located at the start and end of chord in c#

Tags: c#, geometry, ellipse, chord, drawing2d

[image]I am using c# and the library of System.Drawing.Drawing2D to draw some regular geometries. However, I cannot draw a chord of ellipse with specific center point and the points located at the start and end of chord.

Comment: If you're looking for the math equations to calculate a chord of an ellipse, you can search here or many other places for those equations. If you're looking for a .NET library to do it for you, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Here's just one reference that popped up here on SO:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692541/how-to-find-a-point-where-a-line-intersects-an-ellipse-in-2d-c?rq=1

Comment: Post a sketch of what you seek..!